Determine if two sets of lines (pre-vectors) are different in their orientation
Given are two groups of vectors which correspond to orientations. These vectors come from the eigenvalues of material anisotropy tensors and give the principal directions of some material.
These vectors have two important properties: 1) they are always unit vectors, i.e., $|v|=1$ and 2) the sign of the vector is not defined, i.e., $v = -v$. For the latter property, Benger & Hege also call these vectors pre-vectors 1.
Now, I would like to know if these two groups are statistically different, i.e., roughly speaking, I would like to know if the orientation between the two groups is different.
In a paper by Barak et al. 2, they used such orientations and used permutation tests on the distance of the centroids on the unit sphere of the two groups to determine the difference. However, this method only works if all the orientation vectors themselves are "aligned". Otherwise the calculated centroids are not correct.
Here is some python code to generate a set of such vectors to illustrate the problem:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
def generate_random_vectors(theta, phi, n):
    # Normal perturbation to the selected angles
    pertub_t, pertub_p = np.random.normal(0, 0.15, (2, n))
    # flip the signs randomly
    flip = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (n, ))
    t = theta + pertub_t
    p = phi + pertub_p
    return flip * np.array([
        np.sin(t) * np.sin(p),
        np.sin(t) * np.cos(p),
        np.cos(t),
    ])

# Actual points
a_t, a_p = np.deg2rad(60), np.deg2rad(30)
b_t, b_p = np.deg2rad(20), np.deg2rad(10)

## --> these are the pre-vectors/orientations
a = generate_random_vectors(a_t, a_p, n)
b = generate_random_vectors(b_t, b_p, n)


# Plotting...
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = np.zeros((3, n))
# plot vectors
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, *a, color='blue')
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, *b, color='red')

# plot actual points
x, y, z = np.sin(a_t) * np.sin(a_p), np.sin(a_t) * np.cos(a_p), np.cos(a_t)
ax.scatter([x], [y], [z], color='blue', s=80)
x, y, z = np.sin(b_t) * np.sin(b_p), np.sin(b_t) * np.cos(b_p), np.cos(b_t)
ax.scatter([x], [y], [z], color='red', s=80)

ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 1])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

This results for example in this plot:

As you can see the vectors bundle together but some vectors point in the "wrong" direction. The two bundles are visibly separated in this example.
I tried to align the individual vectors, for example by comparing the dot product towards one of the axes vectors (for example $(0,0,1)$) but that always leaves room for some special case.
Thus, my question is in general: What is a proper method to statistically compare such pre-vectors?
Assuming that the method that was used by Barak et al. works well, the goal would be to be able to calculate the centroid of such pre-vectors properly. Thus, an alternative answer could also be to answer the question: What would be a method to construct the centroids on a unit sphere of the two groups without generating problems imposed by the sign of the vectors?
edit: Here is an example why the re-orientation of the pre-vectors is so hard. In the paper of Roberts 4, a method is shown to re-orient such vectors. However, it fails when the vector is near the plane, which splits the sphere into a half-sphere:
def reorient(v):
    """
    Reorients the vectors according to the Rule in Roberts (1988) "A new representation for a Line" paper
    """
    c = v < 0  #: condition vector for l.t. zero
    z = np.isclose(v[1:], 0)  #: condition vector for is zero
    return np.where(
        # If b_z is negative, flip the sign
        c[2] |
        # if b_z == 0, flip the sign according to b_y
        (z[1] & c[1]) |
        # if b_z == 0 and b_y == 0, flip sign according to b_x
        (z[1] & z[0] & c[0]), 
        -v,  # if cond. is true -> flip sign
        v  # else: keep sign
    )

a_t, a_p = np.deg2rad(90), np.deg2rad(40)
b_t, b_p = np.deg2rad(90), np.deg2rad(10)

a = generate_random_vectors(a_t, a_p, n)
b = generate_random_vectors(b_t, b_p, n)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = np.zeros((3, n))
# plot vectors
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, *a, color='blue')
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, *b, color='red')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_title('Original')


ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = np.zeros((3, n))
# plot vectors
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, *reorient(a), color='blue')
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, *reorient(b), color='red')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_title("Reoriented by Roberts' Method")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


I thought that you could maybe find a suitable plane by selecting one that is maximal normal for all the vectors. However, in the end it is a big guessing game which again special cases popping up and being unresolved.

The methods available depend partly on the dimension of the space.  Yours looks three-dimensional, so check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/650193.  (A two-dimensional solution is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260552.) You could also emulate the approach at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34401/919, effectively using the direction of each vector as a binary latent variable to optimize the consistency of vectors within each group.  Finally--and only in 3D or 4D--I believe you could represent vectors as unit quaternions and square them.

@whuber I tried similar approaches to make the vectors consistent but I think that there will always be some special case that is overlooked. Converting them to quaternions and squaring them sounds plausible - I thought that there may be a canonical representation of such a pre-vector any ways. But how exactly is the vector transformed into a quaternion? If I use the vector as the axis but set the angle to zero, the resulting quaternion will also be zero, right? Or do I have to choose a reference axis and calculate the rotation from that axis to the vector?

The hard part is averaging the pre-vectors: after that is accomplished, you can easily change the signs of the pre-vectors so they point in a common direction,  measure the variability of the pre-vectors, perform hypothesis tests, and so on using standard methods of circular statistics.

An intuitively appealing method that generalizes the two-dimensional case (where one simply doubles the angles of all "pre-vectors" in polar coordinates) views these pre-vectors $\mathbf v$ as representing reflections through the half-planes they determine.
The reflection through $\mathbf v$ (assumed of unit length) sends $\mathbf v$ to its negative and otherwise fixes any vector orthogonal to $\mathbf v.$  Consequently--this is easy to check--the reflection is the linear transformation
$$\mathcal R_{\mathbf v}: \mathbf x \to \mathbf x - 2\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf v\rangle\mathbf v$$
where $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ is the usuall inner product.  In any orthonormal basis of the space, the matrix of this transformation is
$$\mathbb R_{\mathbf v} = \mathbb I - 2\mathbf v\mathbf v^\prime.$$
One is thus tempted to use the mean of all such matrices to represent the average of the half-planes determined by a list of $\mathbf v_i;$ that is,
$$\bar {\mathbb R} = \mathbb I - \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf v_i\mathbf v_i^\prime.$$
Because in dimensions $3$ and greater the reflections do not necessarily commute, this average usually is not the matrix of any reflection.  However, it should be close to one (to the extent the pre-vectors tend to be close to a preferred line).  Indeed, in dimension $d$ the eigenvalues of $\mathbb R$ will tend approximate $1$ for $d-1$ of them and the last one will be negative.  That last eigenvalue tells us which eigenvector estimates an the average of these pre-vectors.

For example, here is a scatterplot matrix for are $n=120$ normalized covectors initially generated with a Normal distribution centered at $\mu = (-2.0, 3.0, -2.6).$  They were then randomly negated so they wouldn't point in a common direction.  The eigenvalues of $\bar{\mathbb R}$ are $(0.91, 0.89, -0.80).$  The eigenvector for the smallest eigenvalue of $-0.80$ is $(0.45, -0.70, 0.56),$ which is approximately $1/5.5$ times $\mu,$ indicating its a reasonable estimate of the typical (unsigned) direction. The red triangles lie in the two directions determined by this eigenvector (and are scaled by the eigenvalue because that gives useful information about the variability of the data).  You can see they identify visually reasonable average unsigned directions.

FWIW, this is the R code to perform the calculations and produce the example.
as.reflection <- function(v) {
  diag(1, d <- length(v), d) - 2 * outer(v, v) / sum(v^2)
}
#
# Generate some random vectors with random directions.
#
d <- 3      # Dimension of their space
mu.min <- 0 # The larger (in magnitude), the more focused the vectors will be
mu <- (mu.min + rexp(d)) * sample(c(-1, 1), d, replace = TRUE)
n <- 120    # Vector count
V <- matrix(rnorm(d * n, mu), ncol = d, byrow = TRUE)
s <- sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE)
V <- V * s
V <- V / sqrt(rowSums(V^2)) # This step is needed only for plotting
colnames(V) <- paste0("x", seq_len(d))
#
# Convert V to a reflection representation and average.
#
R <- matrix(rowMeans(matrix(apply(V, 1, as.reflection), ncol = n)), d, d)
#
# Compute the eigendecomposition.
#
obj <- eigen(R)
with(obj, values / max(values))           # Eigenvalues relative to largest
v.hat <- obj$vectors[, d] * obj$values[d] # Scaled last eigenvector
#
# Report the (squared spherical) distance between the estimate v.hat and
# true mean mu.
#
delta <- (sum(v.hat * mu) / sqrt(sum(mu^2)))
v.hat <- v.hat * sign(delta)
(delta <- 1 - abs(delta)) # 0 is best.
#
# Plot the data and the estimate of their mean.
#
if (1 < d && d <= 12) {
  pairs(rbind(V, v.hat, -v.hat), xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), asp = 1, 
        cex = c(rep(1, n), rep(1.5, 2)),
        pch = c(rep(1, n), rep(17, 2)),
        col = c(rep("Black", n), rep("Red", 2)))
}


Do you mean with "last eigenvalue" the third one or the smallest, i.e., the negative one? I think it is the negative one, right? I tested it with some random data and get the same result as with my method - but this seems to be on a better mathematical foundation ;)

I found out by testing some random vectors that there is the case that none of the eigenvalues are negative. This seems to happen if the vectors are spread out over a larger range.

Conventionally, eigenvalues are sorted by decreasing value; I apologize for not stating that explicitly.  Your conclusion in the second comment is correct--and it's a feature, not a problem!  The smallest eigenvalue gives you information about the spread of the (unsigned) directions.  (I never said, and did not mean to imply, there would always be a negative eigenvalue.  When there isn't, you should be very cautious about inferring that its direction gives any precise information about the average direction.)

I see, thanks! And "the eigenvalue [..] gives useful information about the variability of the data" means that the smaller the value is, the less variable is the data? Did I understood that correctly? Or in other terms, if the smallest eigenvalue is positive means that there is a large variability?

The larger the magnitude of the eigenvalue, the less is the variability.  With very consistent directions, the average reflection will be close to their common direction and thereby have an eigenvalue close to $-1.$  This parallels the standard measures of variability in circular statistics, which use the magnitude of the mean vector to quantify variability.

whuber: can we have also the ‚r script‘ related to the example? Thanks.

@Maximilian I hesitated to post it in response to a Python question, but OK, it's now there.

Many thanks! its just so useful to have also the correct implication at hand.

An alternative approach is inspired from the Hough transform. Since the equation of a line in a 2D plane is $y = mx +b$, it is entirely and uniquely described by the vector $[m,b]$, hence by a point in a 2D plane. The Hough transform thus transforms a line of equation $y = mx +b$ into a point at position $[m,b]$.
The same principle can be used for 3D vectors. All your vectors are uniquely described by their azimuth $\theta$ and elevation $\phi$. These values can be conveniently computed using the np.arctan function which yields the same value whether your vector has been flipped or not, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55521711/15196590.
You can thus transform each of your vectors into a 2D point:
a_azimuth = []
a_elevation = []
b_azimuth = []
b_elevation = []

for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    a_azimuth.append(np.degrees(np.arctan(a[0,i]/a[1,i])))
    a_elevation.append(np.degrees(np.arctan(a[2,i]/a[1,i])))
    
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    b_azimuth.append(np.degrees(np.arctan(b[0,i]/b[1,i])))
    b_elevation.append(np.degrees(np.arctan(b[2,i]/b[1,i])))
    
fig,axs=plt.subplots()
axs.scatter(a_azimuth,a_elevation,c='blue')
axs.scatter(b_azimuth,b_elevation,c='red')
axs.grid()
plt.ylabel(r'$\theta$')
plt.xlabel(r'$\phi$')


You can then perform your favorite statistical test to determine whether this distribution has one or two separate modes.
EDIT: to handle the case where $y = 0$, you can either use the Hesse normal transform or use the method outlined in the following paper:
Dalitz, C., Schramke, T., & Jeltsch, M. (2017). Iterative Hough transform for line detection in 3D point clouds. Image Processing On Line, 7, 184-196.

That is quite interesting! I always converted them to spherical coordinates using $\theta=\arccos(z)$ and $\phi=\mathrm{atan2}(y, x)$ - which leads of course to a projection on a sphere. So this method is projecting onto a half-sphere, if I'm not mistaken? The only problem is if $y$ gets zero...

Indeed, I have edited my answer accordingly

I had a look at the paper, especially to the "Roberts’ optimal line representation". That looked very promising! I looked at the original source as well and it gives an algorithm how to orient the "pre-vectors", but it still has the problem for vectors near the $z=0$ plane, as the sign may flip here. Or did you refer to something else in the paper?

I propose now a method, partially inspired by the comments and other answers here. I will not mark it as answer, because it is still a heuristic and maybe there is a method that works without assumptions.
I kept the principle to compare the centroids on the unit-sphere of the sets of orientations. However, I added an extra step to unify the direction of the vectors.
The Algorithm by Roberts fails near the equatorial plane, and thus a better algorithm may find a plane which is maximally orthogonal to the given vectors. This is the same as finding a normal vector on the plane that is maximally parallel with the vectors. The average of all vectors should be such a vector.
The only problem is to check for the negative direction too.
Thus, the calculation of the average was changed, such that for each vector a check is made if the inner product with the current mean is negative. Here is some python code to do this:
def mean_vector(v):
    assert v.shape[0] == 3
    assert v.ndim == 2
    assert np.allclose(np.linalg.norm(v, axis=0), 1)
    mean = v[:, 0].copy()
    for vec in v.T[1:]:
        if np.dot(mean, vec) < 0:
            mean += -vec
        else:
            mean += vec
    return mean / np.linalg.norm(mean)

finally, all vectors can be flipped based on this reference vector:
def orient_vectors(v, ref):
    assert v.shape[0] == 3
    assert v.ndim == 2
    assert ref.shape == (3, )
    return v * np.sign(np.dot(v.T, ref))

I assumed that the centroids of a set of vectors are now the same as finding this mean vector, thus this simplifies the comparison further:

compute the mean vectors for both the sets of vectors
compute the mean of the two mean vectors
orient the individual mean vectors along this reference
calculate the distance as $\arccos(m_1 \cdot m_2)$
do the permutation testing as described in Barak et al.

